# Why is invoking stat with env suggested?

Tags: coreutils, stat

From [coreutils manual, about `stat` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html)

> Due to shell aliases and built-in `stat` functions, using an unadorned
>   `stat` interactively  or in a script may get you different functionality
>   than that described here. Invoke it via `env` (i.e., `env stat ...`)
>   to avoid interference from the shell.

1. What does "shell aliases and built-in `stat` functions" mean?  In
   bash, I didn't find an alias or builtin in or function named `stat`

   ```
   $ whereis stat
   stat: /usr/bin/stat /usr/bin/X11/stat /usr/share/man/man1/stat.1.gz /usr/share/man/man2/stat.2.gz
   $ help stat
   bash: help: no help topics match `stat'.  Try `help help' or `man -k stat' or `info stat'.
   ```
2. Why can "Invoke it via `env` (i.e., `env stat ...`)" "avoid
   interference from the shell"?

   Can't a command following `env` be an alias, built-in command, or
   function?

   Is putting `env` in front of a command a way to specify that the command is an external executable?

Comment: IMO, using an external binary in a script without giving its explicit path is potentially-dangerous anyway, but of course, then you decide between `/bin/stat` and `/usr/bin/stat`. (I wouldn't have `stat` high on my list of commands for which this happens either, unlike `ls` and `rm`, but it's better to have more boilerplate than too little.)

Comment: Oh, and `env` alone won't unset `LANG` which frankly is as much of a danger if you parse command output as anything.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted so much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Bash may not have a `stat` built-in, but other shells may. In fact, a shell may provide built-in versions of any utility it wants to, and a user may override `stat` with their own shell function or alias calling another binary.
2. No. The utility that `env` executes can not be a built-in (try it with `cd` for example). Aliases and shell functions are similarly not allowed.

The manual is just trying to make sure that the user is getting the described functionality. In my opinion, if it wants to be really paranoid, it should also mention that you ideally should call `stat` with its absolute path. This makes more sense on non-Linux systems where the GNU coreutils are an optional extra (often installed in `/usr/local/gnu/bin` or somesuch place, or with a `g` prefix, e.g. `gstat`, `gls`, `gmv` etc.)

Comment: Thanks.Is putting env in front of a command a way to specify that the command is an external executable？

Comment: @Tim Yes, in a way. The `env` utility will only execute utilities external to the shell (and fail otherwise). It also allows you to execute a program with specific environment variables set, e.g. `env CCHACHE_DIR="$HOME/.ccache" ccache -s`. It's more often used for this than making sure that a particular command is an external utility.